# gap filling based on missing timestamp in a time series field measurement

Tags: r, matlab, csv

I have a large field measurement dataset (a csv file).

Dataset has several missing data points due to power failure.

When power failure occurred, it did not generate timestamp as well as missing records at that time.

How can I gap fill the missing timestamp and fill a blank (tab) for the missing records.

Here is the cvs dataset looks like:

```
7/7/15 10:01    45  66  80
7/7/15 10:02    35  18  12
7/7/15 10:04    77  60  35
7/7/15 10:05    77  37  18
7/7/15 10:06    81  57  86
7/7/15 10:07    43  7   80
7/7/15 10:13    69  59  50
7/7/15 10:14    28  81  15
7/7/15 10:15    86  7   20
7/7/15 10:19    22  36  26
7/7/15 10:20    99  39  83
```

In this case, the missing timestamp and records are on

```
7/7/15 10:03
7/7/15 10:08
7/7/15 10:09
7/7/15 10:10
7/7/15 10:11
7/7/15 10:12
7/7/15 10:16
7/7/15 10:17
7/7/15 10:18
```

Please guide me how to fill these gaps with their timestamps and missing records will be filled by "blank" (or tab space) in R or Matlab.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Massaging CSV's in Excel, try this [Null fields and CSV's in Excel](http://superuser.com/questions/390031/how-to-write-null-into-csv-from-excel-for-blank-fields)

Answer (score 0):

Try **tsclean** from the **forecast** package

```
t0 <- ISOdatetime(2015, 8, 6, 0, 10, 0)
t1 <- format(seq.POSIXt(from=t0, length.out=20, by="sec"), "%M:%S")
t2 <- t1[c(1,2, 4:7, 10, 12, 14:15, 20)]

x <- data.frame(date=rep(as.Date("2015-07-07"), 20), 
   t=format(seq.POSIXt(from=t0, length.out=20, by="sec"), "%M:%S"))
y <- data.frame(date=rep(as.Date("2015-07-07"), 11), 
     t = t2, 
     num1 = runif(11))
(z <- merge(x, y, all.x=TRUE))

         date     t        num1
1  2015-07-07 10:00 0.678124372
2  2015-07-07 10:01 0.844224331
3  2015-07-07 10:02          NA
4  2015-07-07 10:03 0.491658140
5  2015-07-07 10:04 0.766373149
6  2015-07-07 10:05 0.006970135
7  2015-07-07 10:06 0.781392461
8  2015-07-07 10:07          NA
9  2015-07-07 10:08          NA
10 2015-07-07 10:09 0.959365082
11 2015-07-07 10:10          NA
12 2015-07-07 10:11 0.652523464
13 2015-07-07 10:12          NA
14 2015-07-07 10:13 0.616461093
15 2015-07-07 10:14 0.215957890
16 2015-07-07 10:15          NA
17 2015-07-07 10:16          NA
18 2015-07-07 10:17          NA
19 2015-07-07 10:18          NA
20 2015-07-07 10:19 0.369941733

require(forecast)
z$num1 <- tsclean(z$num1)
z
         date     t        num1
1  2015-07-07 10:00 0.678124372
2  2015-07-07 10:01 0.844224331
3  2015-07-07 10:02 0.667941235
4  2015-07-07 10:03 0.491658140
5  2015-07-07 10:04 0.766373149
6  2015-07-07 10:05 0.006970135
7  2015-07-07 10:06 0.781392461
8  2015-07-07 10:07 0.840716668
9  2015-07-07 10:08 0.900040875
10 2015-07-07 10:09 0.959365082
11 2015-07-07 10:10 0.805944273
12 2015-07-07 10:11 0.652523464
13 2015-07-07 10:12 0.634492278
14 2015-07-07 10:13 0.616461093
15 2015-07-07 10:14 0.215957890
16 2015-07-07 10:15 0.246754658
17 2015-07-07 10:16 0.277551427
18 2015-07-07 10:17 0.308348195
19 2015-07-07 10:18 0.339144964
20 2015-07-07 10:19 0.369941733
```